# Insert abs into two adjacent terms of the expression

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

Give an expression

```
expr = a - b - c - d - e;
```

I need to add abs between adjacent letters, the desired result is

```
list1 = {Abs[a-b]-c-d-e, a-Abs[b-c]-d-e, a-b-Abs[c-d]-e, a-b-c-Abs[d-e]};
list2 = {Abs[a-b]-Abs[c-d]-e, Abs[a-b]-c-Abs[d-e], a-Abs[b-c]-Abs[d-e]};
```

I tried to use ReplaceList, but couldn't get the correct result

```
ReplaceList[expr, a_ - b_ + c__ /; Length[a - b] == 2 -> Abs[a - b] + c]
```

Do you know the right way?

Comment: (1) `Plus` is `Orderless` and "adjacent" depends on the ordering. Conceptually, "adjacent" and "orderless" are incompatible, but `Orderless` in `Plus` means that terms will be put in the standard order (as defined by Mathematica), which may not be the order the user expects. Is that how you want to apply `Abs`? Additionally, `Orderless` affects pattern matching. -- (2) You give two different results, together called "the" desired result. Does that mean you want separate codes for each?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These give the two desired results.  I had some doubt about the apparent rule for signs, but the following gets the results. Maybe someone clever can find a better way to do the second list.

```
ReplaceList[List @@ expr,
 {w___, PatternSequence[x_, y_], z___} :> 
  With[{s = (-1)^Boole@Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ[x]}, 
   w + s*Abs[s*x + y] + z]]
(*
{-c - d - e + Abs[a - b],
  a - d - e - Abs[b - c], 
  a - b - e - Abs[c - d],
  a - b - c - Abs[d - e]}
*)

ReplaceList[#,
     {w___, PatternSequence[x_, y_]?(FreeQ[#, Abs] &), z___} :> 
      With[{s = (-1)^Boole@Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ[x]}, 
       w + s*Abs[s*x + y] + z]] & /@ ReplaceList[List @@ expr,
    {w___, PatternSequence[x_, y_], z___} :> 
     With[{s = (-1)^Boole@Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ[x]}, {w, 
       s*Abs[s*x + y], z}]] // Flatten // DeleteDuplicates
(*
{-e + Abs[a - b] - Abs[c - d],
 -c + Abs[a - b] - Abs[d - e], 
  a - Abs[b - c] - Abs[d - e]}
*)
```

The following was not asked for, but it gives all possible pairings, including no pairing:

```
    Total /@ FixedPoint[
      Composition[
       DeleteDuplicates,
       Flatten[#, 1] &,
       Map[ReplaceList[
         {
          {w___, PatternSequence[x_, y_]?(FreeQ[#, Abs] &), z___} :> 
           With[{s = (-1)^Boole@Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ[x]}, {w, 
             s*Abs[s*x + y], z}],
          x_ :> x}]]
       ],
      {List @@ expr}]
(*
{-e + Abs[a - b] - Abs[c - d],
 -c + Abs[a - b] - Abs[d - e],
 -c - d - e + Abs[a - b],
  a - Abs[b - c] - Abs[d - e],
  a - d - e - Abs[b - c],
  a - b - e - Abs[c - d],
  a - b - c - Abs[d - e],
  a - b - c - d - e}
*)
```

If you do not remove `Plus` with `List @@ expr`, then you get more pairings, since the `Orderless` attribute of `Plus` allows `PatternSequence[x_, y_]` to match any pair in any order.

Comment: Note that (1) you don't need `PatternSequence`, and (2) you can write just one replacement rule: ```ReplaceList[List @@ expr, {w1___, x_, y_, w2___, q_, r_, w3___} :> With[{s1 = (-1)^Boole@Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ[x],  s2 = (-1)^Boole@Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ[q]},  w1 + s1*Abs[s1 x + y] + w2 + s2 Abs[s2 q + r] + w3]]```

Comment: @Domen Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

For the first solution, we may define a rule that is applied by "ReplaceParts". The rule will replace to successive characters by the absolute value of their difference. As we use the rule in a function, we need to prevent too early evaluation by "Hold":

```
expr = a - b - c - d - e;
rule = {i -> 
    If[i == 1, 
     Abs[expr[[i]] + expr[[i + 1]]], -Abs[-expr[[i]] + expr[[i + 1]]]],  i + 1 -> Sequence[]};

Table[ReplacePart[expr, rule], {i, Length[expr] - 1}]

{-c - d - e + Abs[a - b], a - d - e - Abs[b - c], a - b - e - Abs[c - d], a - b - c - Abs[d - e]}
```

For the second solution, we need a more complicated rule because we now need 2 absolute values. In addition we need the indices of the 2 tuples that we store in the variable "pos". And instead of "Table" we use an function, that is applied to "pos":

```
rule0 := 
  Hold@{#[[1]] :> 
     If[#[[1]] == 1, 
      Abs[expr[[#[[1]]]] + 
        expr[[#[[1]] + 1]]], -Abs[-expr[[#[[1]]]] + 
         expr[[#[[1]] + 1]]]], #[[1]] + 1 -> Sequence[],
    #[[2]] :> 
     If[#[[2]] == 1, 
      Abs[expr[[#[[2]]]] + 
        expr[[#[[2]] + 1]]], -Abs[-expr[[#[[2]]]] + 
         expr[[#[[2]] + 1]]]], #[[2]] + 1 -> Sequence[]
    };

pos = Table[i, {i, 1, Length[expr]}];
pos = Delete[pos, #][[1 ;; ;; 2]] & /@ 
  Table[i, {i, Length[expr], 1, -2}];

With[{rule = rule0},
 ReplacePart[expr, (rule // ReleaseHold)] & /@ pos
 ]

{-e + Abs[a - b] - Abs[c - d], -c + Abs[a - b] - Abs[d - e], 
 a - Abs[b - c] - Abs[d - e]}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
expr = a - b - c - d - e;
lst =List@@expr;
signs=(-1)^Boole[Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ @ #] &/@lst

(* {1,-1,-1,-1,-1} *)
```

```
Flatten[#].Most@signs&/@(MapAt[Abs[First@#-Last@#]&,{2}]/@(TakeList[lst signs,
    {#,2,All}]&/@Range[0,Length@lst-2])) 

(* {-c -d -e + Abs[a-b],
     a -d -e - Abs[b-c],
     a -b -e - Abs[c-d],
     a -b -c - Abs[d-e]} *)
```

**Example 2**

```
expr2 = Join[{a},-Array[x, {9}]]
signs2=(-1)^Boole[Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ @ #] &/@expr2

(* 
   {a,-x[1],-x[2],-x[3],-x[4],-x[5],-x[6],-x[7],-x[8],-x[9]} 
   {1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1} 
*)
```

```
Flatten[#].Most@signs2&/@(MapAt[Abs[First@#-Last@#]&,{2}]/@(TakeList[expr2 signs2,
    {#,2,All}]&/@Range[0,Length@expr2-2]))

(* 
  {Abs[a-x[1]]-x[2]-x[3]-x[4]-x[5]-x[6]-x[7]-x[8]-x[9],
   a-Abs[x[1]-x[2]]-x[3]-x[4]-x[5]-x[6]-x[7]-x[8]-x[9],
   a-Abs[x[2]-x[3]]-x[1]-x[4]-x[5]-x[6]-x[7]-x[8]-x[9],
   a-Abs[x[3]-x[4]]-x[1]-x[2]-x[5]-x[6]-x[7]-x[8]-x[9],
   a-Abs[x[4]-x[5]]-x[1]-x[2]-x[3]-x[6]-x[7]-x[8]-x[9],
   a-Abs[x[5]-x[6]]-x[1]-x[2]-x[3]-x[4]-x[7]-x[8]-x[9],
   a-Abs[x[6]-x[7]]-x[1]-x[2]-x[3]-x[4]-x[5]-x[8]-x[9],
   a-Abs[x[7]-x[8]]-x[1]-x[2]-x[3]-x[4]-x[5]-x[6]-x[9],
   a-Abs[x[8]-x[9]]-x[1]-x[2]-x[3]-x[4]-x[5]-x[6]-x[7]}
 *)
```